# Use common dropdown across multiple worksheets to change single cell

Tags: excel

I have a large file with a Scenario Manager, where changing a single cell on the Summary worksheet changes the visible scenario throughout the rest of the workbook. Data Tables are working a treat providing the headline values for each option.

I'd like to have a drop down on each sheet that when changed will change the same single cell on the Summary worksheet, so I don't need to go back to the Summary sheet every time I want to switch visible scenarios.

This is a simple process if I'm using macros and would be the solution I'd normally jump straight to. But this needs to be done without macros and this is where I'm now struggling.

Does anyone know if this is possible (without macros) and point me in the right direction?

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert combo box (Developer Tab > Insert > Form Controls > Combo Box) on each sheet. Mention linked cell as a cell of the summary sheet (Absolute reference with sheet name). That cell will give you index of the item selected in the drop down list. Then you can insert index formula in the cell you want to change every time to get value of the drop down list. Once you insert it on one sheet you can copy it to other sheets. No macros required.

Comment: Thanks very much Naresh. That was simple. Looking forward to implementing it in anger.

Comment: anger ? Need more clarification on the answer ? How can I help ?

Comment: A slang phrase. What I meant was I tested it out on a sample file to make sure I could get it to work. It does. I will now need to implement it on my working file.